# Looking for a word that means something like "an oversimplified model such that it is not practically useful due to low accuracy"

Tags: single-word-requests

I recall that there is a single word that means approximately this stated definition but can't seem to find it by using google.

I believe I read the word in the context of something regarding politicians passing poor laws based on such models.

I think that it would be useful for others wondering the same thing to be directed to this stackexchange with the answer.

I have searched other stackexchange questions without finding an answer to this questions therefore I believe this question is unique. Although I think some other people may have been searching for the same word successfully.

The answer is not: Oversimplified, dumbed down, or trivialized.

Comment: are you looking for the word "obsolete"  .. something that has lost it's utility due to changes in technology that have replaced it or it not being big enough to accommodate  new standards etc ?

Comment: also 'outmoded' or 'outdated' might be where you are going ..  'outmoded' is almost close enough for me to make an answer

Comment: Sounds like *a shot in the dark*.

Comment: Sounds like a poor analogy.

Comment: In logic there is the notion of *reductio ad absurdum* wrt philsophical arguments. It wouldn't be an abuse or misuse of the phrase to extend it to the accuracy of predictive models, if that is indeed your application. As already noted by @tom22 *obsolete* is also appropriate here.

Comment: It seems as though I've failed to communicate that the word describes a model that is too simple to be practically useful and was always that way. Not one that was useful but is now obsolete. Also, I've never heard obsolete be used a as synonym for something that is overly simplified such that it isn't useful and it doesn't seem as though dictionaries believe the word obsolete means that either.  Seems like many people are hung up on the words "no longer" and not reading the rest of what I've wrote. In retrospect I didn't mean to use those words.

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for the question itself.  The question does not say that the model "is too simple to be practically useful, AND WAS ALWAYS THAT WAY."  The question speaks of a model that was once useful but is no longer useful.  Again, please put  clarifications in the question itself.

Comment: Are you expecting a word which combines the idea that the subject is a model with the idea that it is unusably simple; or would you be happy with an adjective which describes the model as unusably simple but which needs to be combined with the noun 'model' to make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ab2 and BoldBen. This is so long ago now that I can't recall whether the word I had read is a noun or adjective. This is definitely something I will make note of going forward though. So far it doesn't seem like anyone has suggested the word that I had read.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not fond of multi-word answers I will give three here. I think the question is in good faith asking for a term used without exactly knowing which precise meaning they are looking for.

To me "oversimplified" and "surpassed" are very different concepts with 'overly simple'also being very different than "oversimplified" but I'll give the OP the benefit that he did not mean taking something and making it more simple but meant instead that somethings qualities that maintained the same were no longer complex or featured in ways that fit new needs.

The three words below which indicate closer to "surpassed by changed circumstance" are very similar in meaning - I do not feel like the dictionary definitions do them full justice though - I add a bit more further below but even more could be helpful

> [**outmoded** at Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outmoded)
>
> Old-fashioned.
>
> *‘an outmoded Victorian building’*
>
> [**outdated** at Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outdated)
>
> Out of date; obsolete.
>
> *‘outdated equipment’*
>
> [**obsolete** at Oxford Dictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsolete)
>
> 1 No longer produced or used; out of date.
>
> *‘the disposal of old and obsolete machinery’*
>
> *‘the phrase was obsolete after 1625’*

another suggestion (ala @rhetorician in comments) in using the word obsolete in a way of degree

> [obsolescent at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsolescent)
>
> Becoming obsolete.
>
> *‘obsolescent equipment’*
>
> *‘obsolescent slang’*

or as a noun

> obsolescence NOUN
>
> The process of becoming obsolete or outdated and no longer used.
>
> *‘computers are infamous for their rapid obsolescence’*
>
> *‘gunpowder brought about the obsolescence of many weapons’*

I would pick "outmoded" for something that still works but without current expected qualities. It may be a bit less common and 'outdated'might be used instead even if not exactly the same.

I would pick "outdated" for something that really shouldn't be used because of poorer quality results or higher expenses to maintain. Frequently outdated things are still in use but perhaps 'should be upgraded or updated'.  Some outdated things are not in use though and due fit more closely to 'obsolete'.

I would use "obsolete" for things that are completely obsolete (self reference lol), where you can't even practically used it. An once ubiquitous Motorola 'brick' cellphone would not function on current networks ... it is absolutely obsolete.

But the choice is not always clear and any of the three could often mean about the same thing.

Manual typewriter:  still would work on a piece of loose-leaf paper and you could probably still find inked tape online for some models (?)  ... you would NEVER pay someone to type up documents on it.  It would be obsolete, but might also fit definitions of outmoded or outdated.

Film Camera: certain hobbyist professionals still prefer these situationally over digital cameras - which word you picked would express something different in terms of your intended use at the time.

Answer (score 1):

***Toy model*** is a possibility.  However, Toy model does not your comment:

word describes a model that is too simple to be practically useful and **was always that way**

This aspect -- was always that way -- does not appear in your question, only in your comment.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_model) describes a **toy model** as:

> In the modeling of physics, a toy model is a deliberately simplistic
>   model with many details removed so that it can be used to explain a
>   mechanism concisely. It is also useful in a description of the fuller
>   model.

One of the examples the link above gives is:

**orbital mechanics as described by assuming that Earth is attached to the Sun by an elastic band.**

The first example I thought of was the solar system model of the atom, which originally was a serious attempt to explain the structure of the atom.  In this model, the nucleus is like the sun, and the electrons are like the planets orbiting the sun.  However, this model had to be elaborated by introducing quantum mechanics to avoid the prediction that the electrons would spiral in to the nucleus, which would have, n short order, destroyed all the matter in the universe.  So the bare solar system model of the atom was always a model that had no useful explanatory power.  (See [The Bohn Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model))

This is the sort of model you are asking about, as elaborated in your comment, but my impression is that this is not even a toy model; toy models have some explanatory power.

Comment: The word *simplistic* might be an answer in itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Antiquated

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiquated):
outmoded or discredited by reason of age : old and no longer useful, popular, or accepted

They have the following example:

> He has some pretty antiquated opinions about politics.

Answer (score 0):

- **archaic**:  *[very old or old-fashioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/archaic)*.

> Lord Woolf’s report on ethical standards at BAE Systems highlights the intense pressure for reform of Britain’s archaic anti-corruption laws, amid growing embarrassment at the lack of successful prosecutions. (Financial Times)

- **basic**: *[offering or constituting the minimum required without elaboration or luxury](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/basic)*.
- **elementary**: *[of the most basic kind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elementary)*
- **holdover**: *[a person or thing surviving from an earlier time](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holdover)*

> But in reality, Daylight Savings Time is an archaic holdover from a time when people relied on candles all the time. (EOD)

- **layman's terms**: *[phrased so as to be easily understood, without the use of technical or obscure terms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/layman)*.
- **prototype**: *[a first or preliminary version of a device or vehicle from which other forms are developed.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prototype)*
- **rudimentary**:  *[relating to an immature, undeveloped, or basic form.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rudimentary)*
- **superannuated**: *[outdated or obsolete through age or new developments.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superannuated)*

> superannuated computing equipment

Definitions from English Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

A bit obscure, but still apt, I believe, is [non-heuristic](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/heuristic).

For something (say, a theory, or paradigm, or rule of thumb, or . . .) to be heuristic, it is sufficiently explanatory, accurate, and perhaps even elegant, such that it becomes the basis for additional thinking, theorizing, and investigating. If that something is *non-heuristic*, then it is no longer useful or explanatory, or perhaps oversimplified, or just plain inaccurate.

> After Copernicus, the geocentric view of the planetary system became non-heuristic in the science of astronomy.

Answer (score 0):

**outworn**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/outworn)

> no longer accepted, used, believed, etc; obsolete or outmoded

Comment: idiom: behind the times!